# "Natural sorting" in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have an Active Data Provider and GridView as a result where I need to sort teams according to their teamindex. I. e.
A1
A2
A3..

Now I have

```
<?php $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Team::find()->where(['tournament_id' => $model->id]),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 30,
    ],
    'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['teamindex' => SORT_ASC, 'region_id' => SORT_ASC]],
]);

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,...
```

And the result is: A1 A10 A2 A3... 
I understand why strings are sorted this way but I can't find the solution to sort them in the way I need. Please give me some idea how to do it

Comment: the team index  A1, ... A99 is always based on One starting char only  ?   .. show a valida data sample for this column

Comment: Yes, teamindex always one char and numbers from 1 to 12

Comment: `SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY cast(team_index as UNSIGNED INT) asc` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49434/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using a order by based on a calculated  column eg:
coverting as integer  the right part of you string  (assuming that the column in named `team_index`)

```
CONVERT(substr(team_index,2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)

        CONVERT(substr(team_index,2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)

   'query' => Team::find()->where(['tournament_id' => $model->id])
    ->orderBy([ 'left(team_index,1)' => SORT_ASC,
               'CONVERT(substr(team_index,2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)'=>SORT_DESC]),
```

Comment: Tried to use it, changed only DESC to ASC. Result is A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3 ... But I need A1 A2 A3...B1 B2 B3 ...

Comment: asnwer  updated .. just add the order for the first char too

Comment: it works great. thanks for CONVERT(). It is new and useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Cast your column value to an integer explicitly with

```
order by cast(teamindex as unsigned) asc
```

In your code :

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Team::find()
                ->where(['tournament_id' => $model->id])
                ->orderBy('cast(teamindex as unsigned) asc'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 30,
            ],

        ]);
```